# sql one to many

Tags: sql, t-sql

I just want to make sure this is a one to many relationship.

I have a survey which has a checkboxlist where the user can select multiple Problems in the checkbox list.  So I set up three tables

```
SurveyResults             SurveyProblems                 ProblemTypes                   
-------------             --------------                 -------------
SurveyResultID            SurveyProblemsID               ProblemTypeID
                          SurveyResultID                 ProblemName
                          ProblemTypeID
```

is this the correct way to create the database tables if a survey can have multiple problem types?  And this is a one to many relationship, correct?

Comment: I meant one to many relationship....that's a one to many, correct?

Comment: it is many-to-many, bro.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, this is a *many-to-many* relationship, since under this structure, a single `ProblemTypeID` could be associated with multiple `SurveyResultID` *unless* you define a key that enforces uniqueness on `SurveyProblems.ProblemTypeID`.

But for what I understand your structure to be, this will work correctly.

#### Many-to-many example:

In the following sample, there are two possible values for `SurveyResultID`, and the `ProblemTypeID` 1,3 are used in *both* `SurveyResultID`, making this a many-to-many.

```
SurveyProblemsID SurveyResultID ProblemTypeID
1                1              1
2                1              2
3                1              3
4                2              1
5                2              3
```

Note that the surrogate key `SurveyProblemsID` isn't strictly necessary, considering you will need to enforce uniqueness between `SurveyResultID, ProblemTypeID` by defining a composite primary key between them.

```
PRIMARY KEY (SurveyResultID, ProblemTypeID)
```

A true *one-to-many* structure would not need an intermediary table to link surveys to problems. Instead, it could link a foreign key to `SurveyResultID` in the `ProblemType` table directly:

#### One-to-many structure:

```
SurveyResults           ProblemType
---------------------------------------------------
SurveyResultID          ProblemTypeID
                        ProblemName
                        SurveyResultID (foreign key)
```

Even if you do indent a *one-to-many* instead of the *many-to-many* you have defined, your current structure could prove more flexible if you ever needed to expand into *many-to-many* sometime in the future... even though it is a little more complicated to query against having an additional join.

Comment: the surveyProblemsID should only have one 4, correct?  I was thinking this was a many to many.....

Comment: the one thing that I thought was an issue with the one to many structure listed above is I currently only have three problem types, should I avoid listing the same value multiple times in the problem type table?  Does that make sense?  Basically, with that setup I could have 100 rows that all list Problem1 in the ProblemName column.  That's why I was trying to create a ProblemType table  so I didn't repeat values like that.  Not sure what best practice is.

Comment: Repeating ProblemName violates 3rd normal form.  Non key column derived from a key column.

Comment: @user1202606 If you only have 3 problem types and problem types are not uniquely owned by survey results then you must use the many-to-many relationship as you defined it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a survery table and then create a look up table for problems and create a third table to assocate the problems with the survey table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have it right but why do you need SurveyProblemsID?   Use SurveyResultID and ProblemTypeID as the composite primary key so a problem type cannot be repeated.

```
SurveyResults             SurveyProblems                 ProblemTypes                   
-------------             --------------                 -------------
SurveyResultID PK         SurveyResultID PK, FK          ProblemTypeID  PK
                          ProblemTypeID  PK, KK          ProblemName
```

And this is actually a many to many.